# I need help navigating through the api in python

Tags: python, api

I need my little program to give me the current price that is listed in the api using python.
but the problef is I don't know how to get the price from the api.

This is what the api looks like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "website_slug": "bitcoin",
            "rank": 1,
            "circulating_supply": 18353462,
            "total_supply": 17418787,
            "max_supply": 21000000,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 8856.88527092981,
                    "volume_24h": 7633930889.83218,
                    "market_cap": 165283232374.455,
                    "percentage_change_1h": 0.08,
                    "percentage_change_24h": 6.62,
                    "percentage_change_7d": 19.68
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1588256701
        }
    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1588256701,
        "num_cryptocurrencies": 392,
        "error": null
    }
}
```

And here is my python script:

```
import requests, json
from time import sleep

def getBitcoinPrice():
    URL = 'https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/1/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(URL)
        priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.json)['?'])
        return priceFloat
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Error")

while True:
    print(str(getBitcoinPrice()))
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of the `json` module.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html